# Failing to connect to github.com

Tags: git, github, heroku

When I try to push to a Git repository on Heroku I obtain the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxxx.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 9836: Operation timed out

I also obtain the same error when I try to clone any repository from github.com.

I have tried the following command with no success

```
git config --global http.proxy github.com:9836
git config --global https.proxy github.com:9836
```

Comment: …well you've configured Git to proxy all HTTP and HTTPS requests through GitHub. Why did you do that?

Comment: I was advised it was a solution

Comment: It's almost certainly the _cause of_ the problem you're asking about. What problem were you advised this was the solution to? And who advised you to do it?

Comment: I have cleared the 'offending' git config settings and the Heroku push now works.

Comment: I was advised in trying to resolve the following github cloning error:-                                                                                                                              
Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository and the repository exists.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I've added a proper answer below. I don't believe the configuration directives you showed above would help with the permission denied error you mentioned in your comment. Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands [tell Git to route all HTTP and HTTPS traffic through GitHub on port 9836](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpproxy):

```
git config --global http.proxy github.com:9836
git config --global https.proxy github.com:9836
```

When you try to push to Heroku using HTTPS Git now tries to use GitHub as a proxy. As far as I know, GitHub doesn't operate any public Git proxies, and I'm not sure what their purpose would be.

Removing these settings [via](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---unset)

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

or editing your `~/.gitconfig` file manually should resolve your issue pushing to Heroku, assuming you don't actually need a proxy.